# Dynamic className using custom hooks

Tags: reactjs

I cant seem to change the className after callback from an ajax form send.
I get an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable formClass`.
I was using `resetEmail` as a guide to create a `setClass` function so that i can change this classname.
Can anyone lend a hand please.
Thank you.

**edit** when adding `let formClass = setClass('zz');`, I get an error `Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

const useInput = initialValue => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);

  return {
    value,
    setValue,
    setClass: (v1) => setValue(v1),  // << Do I assign here?
    reset: () => setValue(""),
    bind: {
      value,
      onChange: event => {
        setValue(event.target.value);
      }
    }
  };
};


const MyForm = () => {

  const { value:emailVal, bind:bindEmail, reset:resetEmail, setClass:setClass } = useInput('');
  
  formClass = setClass('zz'); // << ! NEED TO CHANGE CLASS

  var regEx = new RegExp(/[^.@a-zA-Z0-9]+/gi);

  let emailStr = bindEmail.value.replace(regEx, "");  
  bindEmail.value = emailStr.toLowerCase();


  const handleSubmit = (ee) => {
    ee.preventDefault();

    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: '/my-url',
      config: { headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }}
    })
    .then(response =>{ 
      resetEmail();
      formClass = setClass('hide'); // << ! NEED TO CHANGE CLASS
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        resetEmail();
        formClass = setClass('hide');  // << ! NEED TO CHANGE CLASS
    });

  }

  return (                                   // need this dynamic
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className={formClass}>
        <label className="" htmlFor="email">My Label</label>
        <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email address" {...bindEmail}/>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">SIGN UP</button>
    </form>
  );
}

const elem = document.getElementById('container');
ReactDOM.render(<MyForm />, elem );
```

Comment: change it to : `let formClass = setClass('zz');` (since you're getting this error : `assignment to undeclared variable formClass`)

Comment: @yaya an edit to the Q has been made.

Comment: you're setting state on each update, that's why you're getting this error. your code is seems logically wrong and messy. `setClass: (v1) => setValue(v1),` is setting the value, so it's same as `setValue`. also it doesn't return anything, so you can't use : `formClass = setClass('zz');` . instead it sets the state `value` and you should bind it to view like : `className={value}` instead of `className={formClass}`. so your code is incorrect and it's not clear what's the purpose of it.

Comment: you probably can add another state variable like : `const [class, setClass] = useState('zz');` and change `setClass: (v1) => setValue(v1),` to : `class, setClass,` , and change: `reset:resetEmail, setClass:setClass }` to `reset:resetEmail, setClass:setClass, class: formClass }`, and change: `formClass = setClass('zz');` to : `setClass('zz');` (and also change `formClass = setClass('hide');` and `show` to `setClass('show');`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the className state inside the MyForm component as it's only anyway being used within that Component.

```
const MyForm = () => {

const { value:emailVal, bind:bindEmail, reset:resetEmail } = useInput('');

//The formClass state
const [formClass, setClass] = useState('zz');

var regEx = new RegExp(/[^.@a-zA-Z0-9]+/gi);

let emailStr = bindEmail.value.replace(regEx, "");  
bindEmail.value = emailStr.toLowerCase();


 const handleSubmit = (ee) => {
   ee.preventDefault();

   axios({
     method: 'post',
     url: '/my-url',
   })
   .then(response =>{ 
     resetEmail();
     setClass('hide'); // << ! NEED TO CHANGE CLASS
   })
   .catch(function (error) {
       resetEmail();
       setClass('hide');  // << ! NEED TO CHANGE CLASS
   });

 }
 return (                                   // need this dynamic
   <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className={formClass}>
       <label className="" htmlFor="email">My Label</label>
       <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email address" {...bindEmail}/>
       <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">SIGN UP</button>
   </form>
 );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! `setClass` was already used so i changed it to `setForm` and it works as expected.